# Integrate API manager with BAM, there are an exception

Tags: wso2

environment:
os: Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.5.0-23-generic x86_64)
java: 1.7.0_25
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
API manager: 1.4.0
BAM: 2.3.0

We follow this guide: http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AM140/Monitoring+Using+WSO2+BAM

When we log in the API publisher Web in purpose of viewing the statics ,it shows an error "No data found. Check BAM server connectivity... Refer our wiki to configure BAM correctly".
And WSO2 AM appears an message:(without call stack)
ERROR - stats:jag "java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Does anyone know what reason is this?

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace of the API Manager

Comment: what are the port offsets you have used in AM and BAM?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to you have not enabled the API Usage tracking from API Manager level from API manager config.

1. Go to ..APIM_HOME/repository/conf/  and edit the file api-manager.xml
2. Enable Usage tracking as below

> ```
>    <APIUsageTracking>
>      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
> ```

Comment: Yes,we had enabled APIUsaggTracking

Comment: Please check  your database source is given properly within BAM and API manager data sources config as in documents. <DataSourceName>jdbc/WSO2AM_STATS_DB</DataSourceName>. Since this will be most due to this APIUsageTracking information has got something wrong.

Since I can recreate this if I give anything wrong into this APIUsageTracking options.

Comment: We proccessed the steps following :http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AM140/Monitoring+Using+WSO2+BAM .The resolution you said is all included in this file and we have done these settings.Do you have any ideas except this guide?

Comment: Also verify that your BAM server ran successfull and it has created "APIMGTSTATS_DB" database in <BAM>/repository/database folder

Comment: The database has been created in the folder successfully.And the name is the same as we write in api-manager.xml and master-datasources.xml.The path to the database we write is "/root/WSO2/wso2bam-2.3.0/repository/database/APIMGTSTATS_DB" ,is it right?If you don't mind,please show us the definition of WSO2AM_STATS_DB you added in the files,thank you.

Comment: <datasource>
            <name>WSO2AM_STATS_DB</name>
            <jndiConfig>
                <name>jdbc/WSO2AM_STATS_DB</name>
            </jndiConfig>
            <definition type="RDBMS">
                <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:h2:/home/Software/wso2bam-2.3.0/repository/database/APIMGTSTATS_DB;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE</url>
                   ..
         </datasource>

Comment: The definintion of WSO2AM_STATS_DB is the same with yours except the path.But the issus still exists.We can't see the statistics.What else would case such problem?

Comment: Better if you do this tutorial from fresh , may be some step missed by you. Please make sure BAM has offset set to value 1  , also refer  http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AM140/Monitoring+Using+WSO2+BAM